# Is the OpenGL greeter (facebrowser) still on the table?

Tags: gdm, login-screen, lightdm

A few years ago, there was an OpenGL greeter (GDM Facebrowser), which would narrow down the user list as you type the user name.

Here is the video: [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBa6me9Avi8). Can someone tell me if it is still under development, or if something similar is planned for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That does look very similar to [LightDM](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/lightdm-to-replace-gdm-login-screen-in-ubuntu-11-10/), in terms of both appearance and capabilities. LightDM will be the new default in Ubuntu 11.10 instead of GDM.

Comment: I think that "screenshot" is a mock up, so I'm not so sure about implementation.

Comment: According to the LightDM wiki page there will be a new login theme that better matches Unity. This is being designed and developed during the Oneric cycle. Until then a simple GTK login screen will be used. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM

Comment: @toros can you post this as an answer? It's the closest to a solid answer I can find :/...